# python import networkx raise Error

Tags: python, lxml, networkx, xml.etree

```
import networkx as net
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Then Ipython show:

```
import networkx.readwrite
from networkx.readwrite.graphml import *
import lxml.etree as lxmletree
Raise Error : module 'lxml' has no attribute 'etree'
```

Comment: Please don't give the error in a screenshot, can you get the text into the question (then it can't expire and can be searched)? A quick search shows that other libraries have had this issue so it might need to be raised on github.

Comment: This question is solved by update the lxml package

Comment: I have solved this question by update the lxml package